# What’s the term for the common part of coordination?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, coordinating-conjunctions

What do you call the part that is common to a list?

Example:

> I buy apples, bananas and citrus fruit.

can be expanded to three sentences

> I buy apples.
> I buy bananas.
> I buy citrus fruit.

How do you call the

> I buy

part?

State the technical term if available, please.

<sup>NB:
The common part may *embrace* the list.</sup>

Comment: It's not a constituent so it doesn't have a name. The "I" is a noun phrase functioning as subject, and "buy" is a verb functioning as predicator in the verb phrase.

Comment: Grammatically it's not a single element; ignoring grammar, you would just call it the "common part" as you do.

Comment: The parts in common.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid it does not have an established technical term (hence I wrote `if available`). Maybe you can _suggest_ names? Please also list and indicate names that are _unsuitable_ because they have a certain meaning to linguists and are thus confusing.

Comment: There, they are direct objects of buy.

Comment: @KaiBurghardt I don't follow you. I gave you the names of "I" and "buy". There are no others. And how can we give you names that are unsuitable -- that would make no sense. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @BillJ I like to view the (list‑prefix, list‑suffix) tuple as _one unit_ so I can (programmatically) extend the sentence to an arbitrary number of members, e. g. add `dates` to above sentence. I like to view the (list‑prefix, list‑suffix) tuple as _one abstract unit_ so I can change the meaning of the sentence, e. g. `The store stocks` instead of `I buy`. My “problem” is probably just a stylistic issue. Currently my code just says _common part_ but that’s not very _descriptive_, is it? By _unsuitable_ I mean, e. g. _complement_ could cause misunderstandings.

Comment: The sentence here has a predicate with a coordinated list. The string you refer to is [subject] + [verb {transitive} ]. Deletion has taken place.

Comment: In your sentence, the main verb applies to three objects: **Main verb**.

Comment: list heading, header, headline

Comment: @KaiBurghardt You seem to be trying to analyse **parts** of a clause as constituents in a non-grammatical way. There's no answer to your question other than the one I gave you earlier in comments. I''m talking, of course, about the sequence "I buy", not the whole sentence. I don't know what you mean by 'common part', which is not a grammatical term.

Comment: @YosefBaskin OK, so in the sentence `I buy, sell and eat apples`, `I … apples` would be the, what, _main object_? To generalize this term for any kind of sentence with coordination, just _main_⁇  @HippoSawrUs Yeah, I considered _head_, too, because at least _sometimes_ it could be the head in a syntax tree. Thank you for your other suggestions.  @BillJ Well, maybe so. Maybe I want to do something “in a non‑grammatical way”. I don’t know. Is this off‑topic for this site? By _common part_ I mean what is “shared” among coordination members (like the `I … apples` at the beginning of this comment).